# Design Practice Retrieve Multiple Users - PHP

Tags: php, sql, performance

Greetings all, I'm looking for a more efficient way to grab multiple users without too much code redundancy.

I have a Users class, (here's a highly condensed representation)

```
    Class Users {

    function __construct() { ... ... }

    public static function getNew($id) {

         // This is all only example code
         $sql = "SELECT Name,Email,Etc.. FROM Users WHERE User_ID=?";

         // Retrieval using prepared statements would go here
         $user = new User();
         $user->setID($id);
         ....

         return $user;
}
  public static function getNewestUsers($count) {
     $sql = "SELECT User_ID,Name,Email,Etc.. FROM Users ORDER BY Join_Date LIMIT ?";

     $users = array();

     // Prepared Statement Data Here

     $stmt->bind_result($id,$name,$email,$etc);

     while($stmt->fetch()) {
        $users[] = Users::getNew($id);
        ...
     }
     return $users;
   }
   // These have more sanity/security checks, demonstration only.
   function setID($id) { $this->id = $id; }
   function setName($name) { $this->name = $name; }
 ...
}
```

So clearly calling getNew() in a loop is inefficient, because it makes $count number of calls to the database each time.  I would much rather select all users in a single SQL statement.

The problem is that I have probably a dozen or so methods for getting arrays of users, so all of these would now need to know the names of the database columns which is repeating a lot of structure that could always change later.

What are some other ways that I could approach this problem?  My goals include efficiency, flexibility, scalability, and good design practice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Simplification of boilerplate SQL binding

This isn't so much a solution as a suggestion:

You're running pretty bare to the metal here as far as sql.  I recommend separating your sql out a bit more, one way that I've found useful is creating a simple database abstraction library function, let's call it `query`. Using Mikushi's example above:

```
// params: $select = full select statement with binding placeholders
// params: $bindings = either associative or numeric array, whichever fits your database binding method better
function query($select, $bindings=array()){
$res = array();

// Loop over each binding here
// Run the bound select statement, get the $res result

while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($res)) {
        $rows[] = $row;

    }
    return $rows;
}
```

Ideal usage, going off of how binding works with PDO because I'm not really familiar with the binding method for mysql_fetch_assoc()

```
$user_data = query('SELECT User_ID,Name,Email,Etc.. FROM Users ORDER BY Join_Date LIMIT :count', array('count'=>$count));
```

That has three benefits: simpler binding, not having to do boiler-plate for single or multi-row select statements (an 80%-of-the-time use case), and potentially an easier time if you ever need to switch databases.

### Factory Pattern to Separate *Creation* of User objects from *modification*

As far as the original issue of user creation, how about using the [factory pattern](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/os-php-designptrns/) to separate the creation of `User` objects from the methods that `User` objects can perform on their own data?

```
Class UserFactory{
    public static function getNewestUsers($count){
        $sql_statement = "SELECT User_ID,Name,Email,Etc.. FROM Users ORDER BY Join_Date LIMIT :count";
        $users_info = query($sql_statement, array('count'=>$count);
        $users = array();
        foreach($users as $user_info){
            $users[] = new User($user_info);
        }
        return $users;
    }
}
```

Use:

```
$user_objects = UserFactory::getNewestUsers( 45 );
```

The user object would then only: use __constructor() on an array of data as Mikushi mentions, and perform alterations on that data (which the factory could potentially have a `function saveUser($user_object)` to save changes.

Comment: I would simply use the full select statement, not -just- a where statement.  That allows the `query` function (I'm suggesting it as an actual library function for reusability, not an object method) to be reusable in a lot of places.  And the binding could be numeric or, for better clarity, it could be string based, e.g. `$bindings['count'] = 45; $bindings['offset'] = 7; $bindings['username'] = 'bob';`

Comment: Excellent! This will make my code Much more flexible and portable.  Your help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Whoops, I clarified the UserFactory class above and added a use case because it's better to make the UserFactory methods static so that you don't have to needlessly instantiate the object.

Answer (score 2):

You could make your User object __construct method accept an array as parameter :

```
class User 
{

    public function __construct($infos) {
        if(is_array($infos)) {
            $this->_initFromArray($infos);
        } else if(is_numeric($infos)) {
            $this->_initFromID($infos);
        } else {
            //Handle error
        }

    }

    private function _initFromArray($userInfo) {
        //Set your stuff in here
    }

    private function _initFromID($userID) {
        //Do your SQL magic
    }

    public function getUsersNewest($count) {
        sql = "SELECT * FROM Users ORDER BY Join_Date LIMIT ?";

        $users = array();

        // Prepared Statement Data Here
        while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($res)) {
            $users[] = new Users($row);

        }
        return $users;
    }

}
```

Something along the line...

Comment: Thank you for your help, I will implement your suggestion